# VB.net Listview Populate

Tags: vb.net, listview, ms-access

I'm trying to populate a Listview in VB.net with items from my access database.

So far, i've managed to fill it with all the items I want, but I need to the items under the right columns. (User and Comment)

Here's all the relevant code:

```
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim comments As New DataSet
    comments = GetComments(classid)

    With CommentsView
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Add("User")
        .Columns.Add("Comment")
    End With

    count = CountRecords() - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To count
        CommentsView.Items.Add(comments.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2))
        CommentsView.Items.Add(comments.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3))

    Next
```

So essentially I want Item(2) under Users and Item(3) under comments. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You are adding Items which equate to rows in a LV, you need to add User and Comment as SubItems (which visually equates to columns).

Comment: So how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding Items which equate to rows in a LV, you need to add User and Comment as SubItems (which visually equates to columns).

```
Dim LVI as ListViewItem
' no need for a count temp var
For i As Integer = 0 To CountRecords() - 1
    LVI = New ListViewItem
    ' whatever you want to show in columns 0
    LVI.Text = (What_Ever_Text_For_Col_0)

    ' add subitem text
    ' this is adding strings from a dataset, but could be any string
    LVI.SubItems.Add(comments.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2))    ' maybe .ToString?
    LVI.SubItems.Add(comments.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3))

    ' add completed LVI to the LV
    CommentsView.Items.Add(LVI)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to work through the logic of this. I will restate it here as a further example.

```vb
Dim count As Integer
Dim comments As New DataSet
comments = GetComments(classic)
```

So far so good.

```vb
With ListView1
  .View = View.Details
  .HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable ' set to whatever you need
  .Columns.Clear() ' make sure columnscollection is empty
            
' Add 2 columns
    .Columns.Add("User")
    .Columns.Add("Comment)
End With
```

Also good. A few small additions.

```vb
For i As Integer = 0 To CountRecords() - 1
   CommentsView.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({comments.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2), comments.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3)}))
Next
```

This line `CommentsView.Items.Add` with the array of fields is the trick I think you're looking for.

My approach to this is slightly different. Here is an example:

```vb
Dim conn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=myDatabase.sql3;Version=3;")
conn.Open()
' I 'm using a table in my database called "lang", a list of languages and language codes.
Dim SQL as string = "Select * from lang;"
Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(SQL, conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "lang")
conn.Close()
'ListView1
With ListView1
   .View = View.Details
   .HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable ' set to whatever you need
   .Columns.Clear() ' make sure columns collection is empty
   ' Add 3 columns
   .Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(0).ColumnName)
   .Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(1).ColumnName)
   .Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(2).ColumnName)
End With
For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
   ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString(), _  
                                         ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString(), _ 
                                       ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2).ToString()}))
Next
```

[ListView1 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf6I3.png)

### A few notes:

1. The columns headers are taken as the column names from the table/dataset
2. I use `Rows.Count` to determine the number of rows
3. I could iterate through the columns to add each one as a column header, but chose to do it this way so you can see the selective adding vs the automatic adding using a loop.
4. This could be improved/changed by looping through the columns and fields.
5. There is no error checking
6. I'm showing here using **SQLite**. This could be any database/table.
7. Sometimes the line continuation doesn't work (**_**). If you copy and paste, you might need to remove those and make that all one line.